# Advanced python/pandas pivoting and filtering?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with information on clients, on which products they spend money and how much money they spend.
i.e.

- client_name: string
- product: [A,B,C]
- profit: float

looking kinda like this:

```
    Clients Products Profit
0  client 1        A    100
1  client 1        A    120
2  client 1        B     30
3  client 1        C     70
4  client 2        A     50
5  client 2        B     40
6  client 2        C     70
7  client 2        A     80
8  client 3        B     90
9  client 3        C     30
```

Now I do have a few problems to figure out:

1) get the profit per client:

`df.groupby(['client'])['profit'].sum()`

gets the job done

2) A bit more tricky one ... I want to see for each client per product the profit (in %) the product makes of the total profit of the client.

```
grouped = df.groupby(['Clients','Products']).agg({'Profit': 'sum'})
grouped.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

seems to get the desired results looking like this:

```
                      Profit
Clients  Products           
client 1 A         68.750000
         B          9.375000
         C         21.875000
client 2 A         54.166667
         B         16.666667
         C         29.166667
client 3 B         69.230769
         C         30.769231
```

3) Now same as in two, but I want to see only clients that have say 50%+ profit coming from product A and also more than 300 total profits.

```
 Expected output here would be client 1.
```

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: It will be better if you provide the sample df and expected output

Comment: but the the df is 36k rows :)

Comment: A sample of it. Around 10 unique rows.

Comment: done, its made up data, but should illustrate the point.

Comment: sum of total profit for a client has to be larger than 300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the sum you can get the clients who have profit more than 300 and convert them to list. Reset the index after finding the percent of profit from products to select client and products.

Later you can do boolean indexing based on the list we got earlier whose profit is greater than 50 and product is 'A' .

```
sumdata = df.groupby(['Clients'])['Profit'].sum()
lst = sumdata.index[sumdata>300].tolist()

ndf = grouped.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum())).reset_index()

ndf[(ndf['Clients'].isin(lst)) & (ndf['Profit'].gt(50)) & (ndf['Products'] == 'A')]['Clients']
```

```
0    client 1
Name: Clients, dtype: object
```

Comment: could you explain a little bit? In particular I am curious about the groupby(level=0) and why we have to use reset_index. Cheers!

Comment: Internet is bit slow here.  Its taking time to update the answer.

Comment: actually that doesn't quite work, at least for me. I get a KeyError:  'Clients'

Comment: I tried it based on the data you gave in question. change it to the column name you have.